# Use non-admin card with composer-rest-server in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am not able to start a `composer-rest-server` without a network admin card.
When I tried a normal user card, it generates the following error:

> Connection fails: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode:
>   transaction returned with failure:
>   AccessException: Participant 'com.tuzz.agloan.Dccb#dccb1' does not have 'READ' access to resource 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network#aloan@0.0.2-deploy.17'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a rule that gives the participant access to the network.

in .acl file, add this rule then update the network and start the REST server

```
rule Rule1 {
   description: "Grant access to the network"
    participant: "com.tuzz.agloan.Dccb"
    operation: READ
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

For more details, you can refer Granting network access control section in [ACL reference](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/acl_language)